# react.js and transmission parameter props in recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I wont transmission parameter `props` in recursion:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { visible: this.props.root, a:this.props.a };
  }  
  toggle(){   this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible});   }
  render() {
    let child, classObj;
    if (this.props.node.child != null) {
      child = this.props.node.child.map(function(node, index) {  return <li key={index}><App a={this.state.a} node={node} /></li>  });
      classObj = {togglable:true, "togglable-down":this.state.visible, "togglable-up":!this.state.visible };
    }

    let style;    
    if (!this.state.visible)  style = {display:"none"}    
    return (
      <div id="tree">{ !this.props.root &&
        <a style={{cursor:"pointer"}} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} className={this.props.node.child.length!=0 ? classNames(classObj) : 'togglable' }> 
            {this.props.node.child.length!=0 ? this.props.node.title : <label ><input type="checkbox" /> {this.props.node.title} </label>}            
        </a>}
        <ul  style={style}> {child} </ul>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const tree =
  {"_id":"_", "child":[
    {"_id":"029", "title":"One title",
      "child":[
        {"_id":"a01", "title":"Two title", "child": []},
        {"_id":"8a5", "title":"News", "child": []},
        {"_id":"02e", "title":"ACL",
          "child": [{"_id":"0b0", "title":"Last Title", "child":[]}]}
      ]
    }
  ]};


React.render( <App node={tree} root={true} a={true}/>,  document.getElementById("app"));
```

But I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

In the line where the `class` of recursively calls itself, I am trying to pass the value `props` stored in the `this.state`:
`<li key={index}><App a={this.state.a} node={node} /></li>`

Code on codepen:
https://codepen.io/alex183/pen/ygEJwd

How best can pass into recursion `props`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an anonymous function for the map, 'this' does not refer to the current App class. If you console.log it you'll see it is undefined. You can either change it to an arrow function which preserves the 'this' context:

```
.map((node, index) => { /* Same as before */ }
```

Or you can copy the value before entering the function

```
const a = this.state.a
// Same as before
.map((node, index) => { /* Same as before, but now a={a} */ }
```

Or you can pass 'this' as the second parameter to map and it will set the context for you:

```
.map(function(node, index) { /* Same as before */}, this);
```